# RSpec - equality match, two different instances

Tags: ruby, rspec

I created a parser, which reads from CSV file and creates objects from every row. It works fine, but now I created Rspec tests. I have:

```
 let(:sample_row) { Call.new(date: '01.09.2016 08:49', service: 'International', phone_number: '48627843111', raw_duration: '0:29', unit: '', cost: '0.00') }

it 'tests parser' do
    expect([sample_row]).to   eql(parse('/file_test.csv'))
end
```

Test outputs - `expected` and `got` - were the same, except of instance id - they were obiously different, because those are two different objects, even if they have exactly the same attributes. So I placed `inspect` method in my class to control the way Object is presented. Now RSpec shows me two exactly the same `expected` and `got` but still test fails. How should I somehow omit the fact two instanes aren't exactly the same if it comes to instance number? I've also tried to use `eq`.

Comment: Your statement should work, at least with `eq`. You need to inspect the result of `parse('/file_test.csv')` a little bit more. What does `puts   [sample_row].inspect; puts sample_row.class; puts parse('/file_test.csv').inspect; puts parse('/file_test.csv').first.class` show?

Comment: I pasted your code into my spec and it shows exactly the same in both cases, also the same Class. The only thing which bothers me is one of the attributes is a number. In one case it showed as 0,55 and in the other - 0.55. I placed .to_f in my inspect and now it shows 0.5 in both cases. Probably it can be done better?

Comment: `0.55` is not always `eq  0.55`. It has to do with float accuracy and representation. You have to work around this. You can use `BigDecimal`, convert it into string, test a delta or do some thing else. Simple keep in mind that floats are not always equal even when they look a like they are equal.

Comment: I tried .to_i to see if it makes any difference - and no, test still fails, even if it gots two exactly the same int numbers

Comment: Can extend your example and show how `sample_row` looks like?

Comment: Did you include `Comparable` and implement `<=>` or do some thing similar for `Call`? Ruby does not compare your attributes on default.

Comment: so it's impossible to use RSpec matchers in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all the given informations `eq` can't work out of the box. You have multiple options:

- compare every attribute like `expect(sample_row.service).to   eq(parse('/file_test.csv').first.service)`
- implement `Comparable`
- use a third party gem like `equalizer` to define equality
- add a method to `Call` that converts all attributes to a hash and compare those Hashes
- create your own Matcher
- ...